# How can i read nc /bin/sh response in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, sh, stdout, netcat

I'm developing some short of netcat client in Java for Android devices.

I have a listen server:

```
$ nc -lvk 192.168.43.1 8080 -e /bin/sh
```

When i send a command like ls using netcat i got a response like:

```
MyFile.txt
MyFile2.txt
```

But when i use my Java code, i don't get the response.

But if i use the command:

```
$ nc -lvk 192.168.43.1:8080 < MyFile.txt
```

I do get the file contents.

I guess the problem is stdout console related.

The java code i use to read output is:

```
while((myString = myBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
  myStringBuffer.append(myString);
}

return myStringBuffer.toString();
```

How can i return the output from sending commands to /bin/sh ?